# Как мессенджер уведомляется о новом сообщении?

Tags: java, c#, tcp, client, messenger

Просветите пожалуйста кто нибудь на эту тему, суть вот в чем:
Допустим есть приложение-сервер некоторого мессенджера где сокет слушает и принимает соединения и.т.д. и есть клиент наподобие viber или whatsapp и тут происходит следующее: первый пользователь отправляет сообщение второму пользователю и сообщение идет через сервер и тут вопрос как сделать чтобы клиент второго пользователя сразу же получил это сообщение?? Может ли клиент отчасти выступать в роли сервера? Или клиент каждую минуту должен опрашивать сервер?

Надеюсь понятно описал вопрос.

Comment: Вообще есть разные варианты. Например, если у вас http сервер, то клиент может запрашивать информацию, а сервер ответит только когда есть чем ответить. Это называется long pooling. Другой вариант - использовать веб  сокеты, если у вас приложение ориентированное на веб (сайт или что т типа веб клиента). Если вы работаете с сокетами напрямую, насколько я помню, сокет позволяет иметь двунаправленную связь, то есть сервер может сам инициировать передачу клиенту, если связь с клиентом уже установлена.

Comment: Да, если удерживать связь это все решит, но не слишком ли накладно удерживать подключение?

Comment: Накладно чем? Это масштабируется горизонтально, если вы мыслите масштабно.

Answer (score 0):

Клиент не должен опрашивать сервер. Вы же используете сокет. Socket.io работает и на клиенте тоже. Т.е. первый юзер эмитит какое-то событие, сервер услышав это событие эмитит новое, которое прослушивает второй юзер на клиенте и как-то реагирует на него. В документации Socket.io все подробно описано.

Comment: Ой, извиняюсь немного напутал с тегами, использую не Socket.io, а java.net.Socket